# How to adjust online basemap to Arcmap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-9.3, imagery, datum, arcgis-online-basemaps

How can I adjust the online basemap imagery file to our existing ArcMap data. Below are steps I perform to add the basemap data.

1. I Added basemap from **"Add Data From GIS Online"** in the file menu and
   then selected **Imagery**  and added to the Desktop.
2. I already have some layer files in our current project in arcmap the details of our

   **Qatar GCS (Datum**)
   :

   ```
   Qatar Projection: Transverse_Mercator 

   False_Easting: 200000.000000

   False_Northing: 300000.000000

   Central_Meridian: 51.216667 

   Scale_Factor: 0.999990

   Latitude_Of_Origin: 24.450000

   Linear Unit: Meter

   GCS_International_1967 

   Datum: D_International_1967
   ```

   ====================================================================

and the **imagery from online data GCS(Datum)** :

```
   WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere

   Projection: Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere

   False_Easting: 0.000000

   False_Northing: 0.000000

   Central_Meridian: 0.000000

   Standard_Parallel_1: 0.000000

   Auxiliary_Sphere_Type: 0.000000

   Linear Unit: Meter

   GCS_WGS_1984

   Datum: D_WGS_1984
```

Now the problem is the added imagery data is looks like it's shifted around 100m difference with our arcmap hole data.

then I tried transformations to adjust with our arcmap data by selecting the same as our **Datum: D_International_1967** in the dataframe properties but not changed anymore. and then i tried different transformations named as Qatar but same result not aligned the data.

am I trying to do the transformations at the right place.?? and any thing i missed here.???

1. **Right click in the arcmap\Datafareme properties\Coordinate system tab\Layers\selecting the desired layer to transform\transormations\convert from (selecting existing GCS)\into (Selecting desired GSC)
2. hit Ok.**

Comment: I guess it would depend on the accuracy of the two datasets. Are you trying to overlay vectors to the basemap??

Comment: I'm just trying to add to my arcmap which currently working..because we have our own image files but this time not working properly so i wanted to add the basemap layer (imagery) after adding to the arcmap some how  it's just aside from the original data in arcmap..

Comment: What's the datum that your image is in?

Comment: Datum: D_Qatar   ( in our existing data)            GCS_WGS_1984- Datum: D_WGS_1984  ( Online imagery file)

Comment: I don't know your skill level or experience, but a few things I would do is 1. Reboot the computer to see if that fixes any glitches/hiccups. 2. Compare the datums of your imagery and arcgis's base maps as you may have to re-project your imagery to get it to work.

Comment: How much is the shift? On the order of 10's of meters, or many KM? How do you know that your vector data is positioned correctly?

Comment: You could always make a copy of your image and georeference it to match the basemap. Like PlyGeo, I am familiar with datums used in Qatar, so this would be my next suggestion to try. In saying this though, I don't know if you have additional data to add, so this suggestion may not be the best solution. But if its just for a single/few images with only labels and no grid (showing coordinates), this would solve part of the issue (best to follow up the transformation process).

Comment: It worked for me changing the projection to romanian stereo 70.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to view data from two datums so will need to use a **[Transformation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003r00000010000000)**.

I'm not familiar with datums used in Qatar but on the Coordinate System tab of the Properties for your data frame you should be able to find a **Transformations** button which should offer you choice(es) based on which datums are in the data frame.

Try these steps using ArcGIS 9.3 (I am using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 but the steps should be basically the same):

1. Start **ArcMap** with a Blank Map
2. Use **Add Data | Add Basemap** to add the **Imagery** basemap
3. Use the **Find** tool to locate and Zoom To the **State of Qatar** - then set the scale to 1:250000
4. Use the **Coordinate System** tab of the **Properties** for the **Basemap** layer and you should see that it is **WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere**
5. To change the Coordinate System of the **Data Frame** for display (do NOT use the Layers part of the dialog) choose **Predefined>Projected Coordinate Systems>National Grids>Asia>Qatar National Grid**.
6. Hit the **Transformations** button and chose to Convert from **GCS_WGS_1984** to **GCS_Qatar_1974** using **Qatar_1974_To_WGS_1984_3**
7. Hit **OK** to accept the Transformation and **OK** again to display the map in the Qatar National Grid coordinate system

I don't have any data to add and observe the result but am confident that if it was in Qatar National Grid it would line up.  However, depending on where in Qatar it was it might be that Qatar_1974_To_WGS_1984_1 or Qatar_1974_To_WGS_1984_2 were slightly better than my first choice above.

Comment: Why would a datum transformation be required if the map service, as well as the vector data, both are in WGS84 datum?

Comment: I read D_Qatar as being potentially a variation on WGS84 but am no geodesist so happy to defer to you on this.

Comment: Ok Got it. I misread that as being WGS84 as well.

Comment: I tried transormations in dataframe properties but i came up with no luck. is there any other way to adjust the map with data.?

Comment: Which transformation method did you choose to try? Also, I would recommend you revise your question to provide detailed steps starting with Blank Map for how you try to align one dataset with the online basemap.

Comment: I update the question with adding some more details.

Comment: Can anyone answer this question please...

Comment: Thanks Poly Geo, i followed your steps and do the same but one thing i want to make sure that i'm using Dataframe properties and changing the transformations because i have only (General,Source,Layers,Cache and Advanced) for the basemap layer. Since i don't have enough reputations in this site i couldn't post the pictures to show you the exact peoblem so that i posted some pictures in my blog http://ganeshmstech.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-adjust-online-basemap-to-arcmap.html please check those screen shots and advise me what should i do further. thanks

Comment: On the Coordinate Systems tab you should not be doing anything with any of the Layers - not even the Layers section of that dialog.  It is many years since I used 9.x but I think you choose the Coordinate System to display all layers in using Predefined>Projected Coordinate System>National Grids> etc

Comment: It's Working perfect now...Thank you very much for your help..!! i amended your answer with this final step and done this question as answered please check it out and add more information if anything necessary to help others...!!

Comment: Am glad it is working - I looked at your edit but was concerned it removed a key step that I think still needs to be there.  I have now updated step 5 to make what I was trying to describe without access to the 9.3 dialogs a bit clearer based on your comment.